# Date subtraction in rails 3?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In rails date subtraction

```
Date.new(2001,2,3) - Date.new(2001)
#=> (33/1)
```

what is that `/1` indicates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a [`Rational`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Rational.html):

```
(Date.new(2001,2,3) - Date.new(2001)).class
#=> Rational
```

and this is just how  k's are displayed via [`inspect`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Rational.html#method-i-inspect):

```
Rational(1)
#=> (1/1)
```

if you want an `Integer`, then just convert it to one:

```
(Date.new(2001,2,3) - Date.new(2001)).to_i
#=> 33
```

Comment: how nice ruby reflection class is :)

Answer (score 1):

This is just a [rational number](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Rational.html):

```
(Date.new(2001,2,3) - Date.new(2001)).class
#=> Rational
```

You just got the number of days between the two date in rational format.